# Cmder alias to existing loop

Tags: node.js, bash, loops, alias, cmder

I have a loop that basically recursively removes folders by foldername:

```
for /d /r . %d in (node_modules) do @if exist "%d" rm -rf "%d"
```

This works fine, if i run it by itself inside cmder, it will loop from the current set directory and then remove any instance it finds.

I figured seeing as it's a one liner I could easily add it as an alias to cmder by doing:

```
cnode=for /d /r . %d in (node_modules) do @if exist "%d" rm -rf "%d"
```

cnode == (clean node), it's just something easy to remember, however when I run the command it doesn't actually do anything at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find ./node_modules -name 'foo' -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;`

or find in node_modules any directory named 'foo' and run `rm -rf` on it

it can wildcard too:

`find ./node_modules -name 'foo*' -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;`

if you want it to be an alias you have to make it a function.
create a file `aliases` and make it:

`#!/bin/bash
function remove_dir () {
 find ./node_modules -name "'$1*'" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
}`

and what someone else said, you're doing batch on windows, if you can use bash, i've given it to you

Comment: I just changed this to `cnode=find . -name "node_modules" -type d -prune -exec rm -rf {} ;` as it was spitting out 'missing argument for exec', A quick google fixed this for me. Also want to search the current directory down, looking for the node_modules folder, but that was an easy fix too, thanks mate!